# What decides when the git reference-transaction hook runs?

Tags: git, refer

I have git 2.28.0

I have a remote branch and a local branch that both point to the same commit.
If I checkout the commit or the remote branch I see the reference-transaction hook run, but if I checkout the local branch I don't.

I can't find any reference to this behaviour in the docs. Is this expected? and if so why? and where is it documented?

Comment: The ref-transaction-hook is a bit of a work in progress (there were some adjustments going in to Git 2.29), but the *goal* is to run the hook before making any *changes* to a ref. A checkout operation just *reads* a ref so wouldn't invoke it. However, a checkout of a commit hash ID, or a remote-tracking name, wouldn't either—except that these update `HEAD`, which is a pseudo-ref. The fact that the pseudo-ref `HEAD` gets updated (sometimes even for regular checkout) is where things are a little fuzzy.

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you should expect, but it is probably worth scanning through the [Git mailing list archives](https://git.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/GitCommunity).

Comment: @torek I did that before posting here, I couldn't find anything at all about reference-transaction and HEAD

Comment: Hm. I haven't been keeping up with the ref-transaction-hook stuff myself but I thought there was a proposed documentation update included in it. If not, and if the 2.29 release candidate still doesn't document it, you might want to start a mailing list discussion.